# Better Algorithms than Horner's Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was given a homework question on my assignment regarding the Horner's algorithm.
I used the standard C++ implementation of the algorithm.

```
int horner(int poly[], int n, int x)
{
    int result = poly[0];  // Initialize result

    // Evaluate value of polynomial using Horner's method
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        result = result*x + poly[i];
}
```

However, this algorithm has an efficiency of O(n) for each x. Now consider that there were many x to be substituted on the same set of coefficients. I got the idea because my teacher used the same set of constants each time for testing my code. 
Is there not a more efficient way of substituting different x on the same set of coefficients without having to do a second round of the algorithm with efficiency O(n)?

Comment: First, I think that permutation does not mean what you think it means. Second, you are doing one operation for every term - I don't see any way in which you could avoid that, since you don't know in advance what the coefficients are.

Comment: @AaronI Thanks for the correction of the word 'permutation'. However, for the second question, I have mentioned quite bluntly that there are many x that  are to be substituted for the SAME SET of coefficients unlike what is shown in the function.

Comment: I guess your question boils down to: if I have `r1 = f(poly, n, x)` can I calculate `f(poly, n, y)` as some function of `r1, x, y`, rather than calculating the whole polynomial again using `y`.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is what I am trying to find out. Since this is an algorithm question, I thought it would be appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: You cannot optimize code until you know it gets used.  A function like this will be called many times with the exact same poly[] array content but always different x values.  Reason out for yourself how you could store intermediate calculation values and re-use them again later when the function is used like that.

Comment: I don't think such an algorithm is possible.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Fourier Transform chapter of the CLR algorithms book describes an efficient algorithm for evaluating a constant polynomial on a large _vector_ of x values simultaneously.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot